# SYMFONY 5 - Query Builder in a form

Tags: php, symfony

I have a little problem recovering the Campaigns name in my form. What my form does is display a
user group and group name which works fine but it the drop-down list of campaigns name is empty ,
I have been trying  to retrieve the list of campaigns name using query_builder  but without success .. here is my controller  code:

```
namespace App\Controller;
     
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Entity\VicidialUserGroups;
use App\Form\VicidialUserGroupsType;
use App\Form\CentreApplGrpsType;
use App\Form\VicidialUserGroupsAdminType;
     
class SomeController {   
  
  public function newbyadminAction(Request $request ): Response {
             
    $session = $request->getSession();
    if ($session->get('niveau') !== 9) {
      throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    } 
     
    $groupe = new VicidialUserGroups();
    $centreapplgrp = new CentreApplGrps();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
             
    $idgroupes = $em->getRepository(CentreApplGrps::class)->groupesidparappel($session->get('appel_id'));
    $idcampagnes = $em->getRepository(VicidialUserGroups::class)->campagnesidparappel($idgroupes);
     
    $form = $this->createForm(VicidialUserGroupsAdminType::class, $groupe , array('idcampagnes' => $idcampagnes));
    $form->handleRequest($request);
     
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      $centreapplgrp->setUserGroup($session->get('call_triptyque') . '_' . $form->get('userGroup')->getData());
      $centreapplgrp->setCallcenterId($session->get('appel_id'));
      $groupe->setUserGroup($session->get('call_triptyque') . '_' . $groupe->getUserGroup());
      $groupe->setGroupName($session->get('call_triptyque') . '_' . $groupe->getGroupName());

      $em->persist($groupe);
      $em->persist($centreapplgrp);
      $em->flush();
    }
    return $this->render('groupe/nouveau_groupe_par_admin.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));       
  }
}
```

here is my form code :

```
namespace App\Form;
    
use App\Entity\VicidialUserGroups;
use App\Entity\VicidialCampaigns;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use App\Repository\VicidialCampaignsRepository;
    
class VicidialUserGroupsAdminType extends AbstractType {
    
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options {   
    $builder
      ->add('userGroup', TextType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Id Groupe',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
      ))
      ->add('groupName',TextType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Nom du groupe',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
      ))
      ->add('allowedCampaigns', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => VicidialCampaigns::class, 
        'label' => 'Campagne',
        'choice_label' => 'campaignName',
        'placeholder' => 'Les campagnes', 
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
        'query_builder' => function (VicidialCampaignsRepository $er) use ($options) {
          return $er->formcampagnesparappel($options['campagnesid']);
        }
      ));
  }
    
  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
      'data_class' => VicidialUserGroups::class,
      'campagnesid' => array()
    ]);
  }
}
```

here is my VicidialCampaignsRepository :

```
namespace App\Repository;
    
use App\Entity\VicidialCampaigns;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
    
/**
 * @method VicidialCampaigns|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method VicidialCampaigns|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method VicidialCampaigns[]    findAll()
 * @method VicidialCampaigns[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class VicidialCampaignsRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository {
        
  public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry) {
    parent::__construct($registry, VicidialCampaigns::class);
  }
   
  public function formcampagnesparappel($cc) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
      ->select('c')
      ->where('c.campaignId IN (:cc)')
      ->setParameter('cc', $cc);
    
    return $qb;
  }
}
```

here is my CentreApplGrpsRepository  code :

```
namespace App\Repository;
    
use App\Entity\CentreApplGrps;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
    
/**
 * @method CentreApplGrps|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method CentreApplGrps|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method CentreApplGrps[]    findAll()
 * @method CentreApplGrps[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class CentreApplGrpsRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository {

  public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry) {
    parent::__construct($registry, CentreApplGrps::class);
  }

  public function groupesidparappel ($centreappl) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('g')
      ->select('g.userGroup')
      ->where('g.centreappel = :centreappl')
      ->setParameter('centreappl', $centreappl);
    
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
  }
}
```

here is my screenshot :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vquo2.png)

Comment: what do you have in $idgroupes?

Answer (score 0):

In the statement `$form = $this->createForm(VicidialUserGroupsAdminType::class, $groupe , array('idcampagnes' => $idcampagnes));` the form's option array has the key `'idcampagnes'`. Yet your form class expects a key in its options array of `'campagnesid'`. The option's array keys should be identical. For consistency you should probably change the form call options array to `array('campagnesid' => $idcampagnes))`, but that's up to you.

Comment: i change the option array to campagnesid same for variable $campagnesid and nothing happen :/ still empty

Comment: You might try confirming that intermediate steps are providing the expected results. For example, in the controller, insert `dd($idgroupes);` following the line `$idgroupes = $em...` to be certain `$idgroupes` is not null. Then maybe the same idea in the `VicidialCampaigns` repository to be sure `$qb` is not null. At least, this is how I track down my own bonehead errors!